# Eclipse RCP. How to make different ToolBarItems for different Perspectives

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am quite new to Eclipse RCP development.
In my Eclipse RCP application there are different perspectives. I want them to have different ToolBarItems. According to the official documentation the contents of this toolbar change based on the active perspective. But after tons of googling I still have no idea how.

My best idea is as follows:

First I create the items and I add them to toolbar and coolbar

```java
protected void fillCoolBar(ICoolBarManager coolBar) {
    IToolBarManager toolbar = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT | SWT.RIGHT);

    ActionContributionItem saveItem = new ActionContributionItem(saveAction);
    saveItem.setId(ApplicationActionBarAdvisor.SAVE);
    toolbar.add(saveItem);

    ActionContributionItem saveAllItem = new ActionContributionItem(saveAllAction);
    saveAllItem.setId("saveAllItem");
    toolbar.add(saveAllItem);

    coolBar.add(new ToolBarContributionItem(toolbar, "main"));
}
```

and then, in the Perspective class I override the createInitialLayout() method and I just hide the unnecessary item.

```java
@Override
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();
    PageLayout pl = (PageLayout) layout;
    pl.addHiddenToolBarItemId(ApplicationActionBarAdvisor.SAVE);
    pl.setEditorAreaVisible(false); 
    pl.addStandaloneView(View.ID,  false, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f, editorArea);
    pl.getViewLayout(View.ID).setCloseable(false);
}
```

It does not work, but I have no idea what I am missing. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is `PageLayout`? There is no such class in Eclipse 4

Comment: package org.eclipse.ui.internal PageLayout

Comment: That class does not exist in Eclipse 4 and in any case it is **internal** - you are breaking the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point and contriubte an `actionSet` to the perspective.

For example, this is part of the JDT plugin:

```xml
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">

  <perspectiveExtension targetID="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugPerspective">
     <perspectiveShortcut id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective"/>
     <perspectiveShortcut id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaBrowsingPerspective"/>
     <actionSet id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaActionSet"/>
     <showInPart id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer"/>
  </perspectiveExtension>
```

Note: Do **not** use internal classes such as `PageLayout` they may change at any time and in fact this class was in Eclipse 3 but has been deleted in Eclipse 4.

Comment: Thanks. Which class/interface should my Perspective class implement/extend?

Comment: You implement `IPerspectiveFactory` as always. You can use `IPageLayout` but you can't cast that to `PageLayout`.

Comment: I see. IPageLayout however does not have addHiddenToolBarItemId. (I only used PageLayout in order to gain access to addHiddenToolBarItemId) . But intstead of this I need to use layout.addActionSet("saveItem"), correct?

Comment: addHiddenToolBarItemId is not part of the official API so you must not use it. There is a lot of very badly written code around on the net for Eclipse, much of it breaks when you move to Eclipse 4.